# How to grab all defaults from `argparse`?

Tags: python, argparse

I have an argument parser like so:

```
def args_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='myparser')
    parser.add_argument('--k', type=int, default=100, help = 'numbers')
    return parser
```

Now, all I want to do is just get the default mappings, like so:

```
args = args_parser()
```

And then I want `args['k']` to return `100`, since that is the default.  How do I make this happen?

Comment: `args = args_parser().parse_args()`? You'd have to do `args.k` to get `100`, but otherwise...

Comment: `parser.parse_args().k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the .parse_args() function on your parser object in order to actually return the command-line arguments parsed and assigned to attributes as defined in your .add_argument() statement.  So something like:

```
parser = args_parser()
args = parser.parse_args()
k_value = args.k
```

The 'args' variable returned by .parse_args() will have attributes assigned corresponding to the names you assign to it via the .add_argument() call, although if there is no default and the user does not provide a given argument its value will be 'None'.

Answer (score 1):

This should do that for you. I think you should be able to find this in the Python docs on `ArgumentParser` as well:

```
vars(args.parse_args())['k']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def args_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='myparser')
    parser.add_argument('--k', type=int, default=100, help = 'numbers')
    return parser

parser = args_parser():
args = parser.parse_args([])    
print(args)     # see all values
print(args.k)   # see just the k attribute
```

`parse_args()` parses the `sys.argv` as provided in the commandline.  `parse_args([])` parses an empty list, same as if you had called the script without arguments.  I regularly test a parser setup with calls like this.

With your argument definition the `[]` works fine and shows the default `k` value.  With other defintions, `[]` might produce an error.  For example if you included

```
parser.add_argument('infile', help='positional file name')
```

now a string is required.  For a simple positional like that a default is not needed nor does it make sense.  But other parameter combinations can make use of a default.

I could show you how to access the `default` as set in the `add_argument` command, but that involves some undocumented features.  In addition there are several ways of defining defaults, so the topic can get complicated.

Anyways simply running the `parse_args` with an empty list is often enough.

You can also make it display the default in the help line with a little addition:

```
parser.add_argument('--k', type=int, default=100, help = 'numbers, %(default)s')
```

For example, in an interactive `ipython` session:

```
In [73]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [74]: parser.add_argument('--k', type=int, default=100, help = 'numbers, %(default)s')
Out[74]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--k'], dest='k', nargs=None,
    const=None, default=100, type=<class 'int'>, choices=None,
    help='numbers, %(default)s', metavar=None)

In [75]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--k K]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --k K       numbers, 100

In [76]: parser.parse_args([])    # displays args
Out[76]: Namespace(k=100)
In [78]: parser.parse_args(['--k','200'])
Out[78]: Namespace(k=200)
```